# apache mod_rewrite http_user_agent with special character issues

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having an issue with a spam bot/crawler coming to my website with requests that show up like so in apache logs:

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7128 "-" "\x09Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0"
```

The odd difference in these requests is that for some reason the user agent is preceded by a tab (`\x09`) so I have tried to create a .htaccess mod_rewrite filter for these.

I have been unsuccessful thus far at creating a RewriteCond appropriate to deny these requests. I have tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^\x09Mozilla [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00|%09).* [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

With `%09` (the tab character) being the most important operative clause in the second RewriteCond (the others thrown in for added security).

Where is my syntax error? How can I block these requests?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, ending up using the following, seems to be stopping the bots in their tracks with a 403 error:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Mozilla/5\.0.*Windows\ NT\ 5\.1;\ rv:5\.0.*Gecko/20100101\ Firefox/5\.0 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00|%09|\t|\x09).* [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is  that when you type \x09, that's not a special character - it's the characters \, x, 0 and 9. If you want a tab, try using \t instead - that's the regexp version of tab. So the RewriteCond should look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^\tMozilla [NC,OR]
```

Comment: This is not effective in stopping the requests either. I'm still seeing said requests satisfied with an `HTTP 200` in the Apache log even after changing the .htaccess as you advised